# LINQ groupby and count

Tags: linq, count, group-by

I have the following LINQ query:

```
From metasect In DirectCast(Form.ChildDocBox.Tag, META_DOCUMENT).META_SECTIONS
From metaset In metasect.META_SETS
From metacell In metaset.META_CELLS
From lookup In metacell.CHILD_META_CELL_CELLS_LOOKUPS
Where lookup.PARENT_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_DOCUMENT.META_DOC_ID = docToDelete.META_DOC_ID
Select metasect.META_SECT_NAME + " gets from " + lookup.PARENT_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_SECT_NAME Distinct
```

The **Select** instruction selects an expression which can be repeated, because there are multiple *lookups* on the same couple of parent and child *metasections*, that's why I added a  **Distinct** clause.

Now, I'd like to count how many *lookups* are there for each parent/child couple.

Something like

```
SELECT metasect.META_SECT_NAME + " gets from " + lookup.PARENT_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_SECT_NAME,
       COUNT(lookup)
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY metasect.META_SECT_NAME + " gets from " + lookup.PARENT_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_SECT_NAME
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with a 2-step approach

```
Dim all = From metasect In DirectCast(Form.ChildDocBox.Tag, META_DOCUMENT).META_SECTIONS
          From metaset In metasect.META_SETS
          From metacell In metaset.META_CELLS
          From lookup In metacell.CHILD_META_CELL_CELLS_LOOKUPS
          Where lookup.PARENT_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_DOCUMENT.META_DOC_ID = docToDelete.META_DOC_ID
          Select lookup


For Each grp As IGrouping(Of String, ICELLS_LOOKUP) In
         all.GroupBy(Function(l) l.CHILD_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_SECT_NAME + " gets from " + l.PARENT_META_CELL_META_CELL.META_SET.META_SECTION.META_SECT_NAME)

    'do some stuff with grp.Key() & grp.Count()'

Next
```